# field_get_items drupal method causing site error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field

I am using the field_get_items method on a page, but while the method *works as intended*, I have noticed that for the user login portion of the site the window loads an error message making it impossible to login. I narrowed it down to the one line of code that is causing the problem, and it is as follows...

```
$contact_array = $field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_event_contact');
```

Is anyone aware of a known bug in Drupal that is related to field_get_items? Is there anything I can do to improve the method? Thanks!

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information for us to help. Where is this code located? Where is the $node variable coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $node variable that you are passing might not be defined.

Please enable error reporting to see the actual message that is causing issue.

Also, it would be helpful if you paste whole of user submission code here.

Comment: You nailed it- the $node variable was the issue. Thanks very much for your response Shiks.